# Give site members the "Stop sharing" option

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions, sharing, restricted-access

I'm trying to set up a database for scientific reports, which will only be used by the project managers who prepare those reports.

Since some projects involve confidentiality issues, I would like to give users the option to "Stop sharing" (under "Manage access", for a selected file) a file they uploaded, without turning them into owners of the site, ideally. The only way I found to make this option available for them is to turn them into owners, but there are other things they should not tinker with, so I would like to avoid that solution.

The reason for that is that the database I'm building allows project managers to see past projects and to search through them, and sometimes they will need to search their own reports, or share it with one or two colleagues only ; other project managers, in the case of confidential projects, should not be able to find those.

Does someone have something to suggest here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a Flow that runs on the selected document and let the flow reset all sharing with the action **Stop sharing an item or a file**.

[image]